# How to apply theme to select

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I want to use this select:
http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/12138056/Selectmenu

But I can't understand, how can I use one of these themes in own project?
What should I do, to style selects on own page?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

**Theme Switcher**

If you want to add a theme switcher then just add the following to your page header:

```
<script src="http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/themeswitchertool/" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#switcher').themeswitcher();
});
</script>
```

then add this to the body

```
<div id="switcher"></div>
```

---

**Single Theme**

If you just want a single theme of your choice, then you can just link to one of the google hosted files. See [this blog entry](http://blog.jqueryui.com/2011/01/jquery-ui-1-8-9/) for a list of links you can use. Example that could be added to your page header:

```
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/ui-darkness/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" >
```

Comment: No, I don't want change it dynamically.

Comment: That is what the theme switcher does. If you don't want to use the theme switcher then write your own script to load the selected css file.