# how to change input box into select on clicking

Tags: php, javascript

I have an input box that contains value 'male'. How can i change that input box 
into select that will contain two options 'male' and 'female' onclick. Any help would be appreciated

```
<?php

echo '<input type="text" name="gender" id="gender" value="male" onclick="changeSelect();"/>';

?>
```

htmlPage------------------------

```
<script type="text/javascript" > 

 function changeSelect(){


}


</script>
```

Comment: You would use a select element???????? This is what 99.99% of users would expect.

Comment: why don't you use select box directly instead of input box?

Comment: i think you want a style of a input box, but on focus an select box right? why you render a second select box as hidden and show it on click?

Comment: why you dont use the select (combobox) or radio button for gender?

Comment: Part of the requirement of being a good webdeveloper is guiding the client away from their ill conceived ideas. Styling a selectbox would be a better idea here, or if you really must, use a UI framework that supports themes. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4985452/how-to-apply-theme-to-select

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div id="mydivid"><input type='text' onclick='changeSelect()' value='Men' /></div>

<script>
function changeSelect()  {
    document.getElementById("mydivid").innerHTML = "<select name='gender'><option value='male'>Male</option><option value='female'>Female</option></select>";
  }
  </script>​
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aNRky/1/)

Answer (score 2):

without jquery try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function toggle(me, other) {
    me.setAttribute('style', 'display: none');
    var otherElement = document.getElementById(other);
    otherElement.removeAttribute('style');

    if(otherElement.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'select') {
        myValue = me.getAttribute('value');
        for(var n = 0; n < otherElement.options.length; n++) {
            if(otherElement.options[n].getAttribute('value') == myValue) {
                otherElement.options[n].select;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        myValue = me.options[me.options.selectedIndex].getAttribute('value');
        otherElement.value = myValue;
    }
}
</script>

<input onclick="toggle(this, 'the_select');" id="the_input" />
<select onchange="toggle(this, 'the_input');" id="the_select"  style="display:none">
    <option value="male">male</option>
    <option value="female">female</option>
    <option value="alien">alien</option>
</select>
```

with jquery try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function initToggle(select, input) {
    var s = jQuery('#' + select);
    var i = jQuery('#' + input);
    i.click(function(){
        i.hide();
        s.show().val(i.val());
    });
    s.change(function(){
        s.hide();
        i.show().val(s.val());
    });

}

</script>

<input id="the_input" />
<select id="the_select"  style="display:none">
    <option value="male">male</option>
    <option value="female">female</option>
    <option value="alien">alien</option>
</select>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function(){
        initToggle('the_select', 'the_input');
    });
</script>
```

or with jquery and dynamicly

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function initToggle(input, options) {
    var s = jQuery('<select />')
        .hide();
    for(var n = 0; n < options.length; n++) {
        s.append(jQuery('<option/>')
            .attr('option', options[n])
            .html(options[n]));
    }
    var i = jQuery('#' + input).after(s);
    var conf = function(a, b, method) {
        a.unbind(method).bind(method, function(){
            a.hide();
            b.show().val(a.val());
        });

    }
    conf(i, s, 'click');
    conf(s, i, 'change');       
}

</script>

<input id="the_input" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function(){
        initToggle('the_input', ['male', 'female', 'alien']);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: +1 for non jquery version, but you have a typo `otherElement.options.lenght`

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example with jQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/mJ7s6/1/

**JavaScript**

```
$('#textInput').click(function () {
    var input = $(this),
        parent = input.parent();
    $('<select><option value="male">male</option><option value="female">female</option>').insertAfter(input);
    input.remove();
});​
```

Comment: jQuery's `replaceWith` or `before` methods would work better here.

Comment: I'm getting the input box by id. It's a way to select element provided by jQuery

Comment: @MinkoGechev there is no mention of jquery

Comment: It would be better if it auto selects the correct dropdown option as currently, if the value is Female, onclick it will show Male as the selected dropdown. Also, I don't think removing the element it best, hiding it would be better then you can switch back to a text input when the focus leaves.

Comment: @MrCode whilst you are correct in your assessment I don't think the OP has thought that far ahead, or requested these extra features. It's far better that this idea isn't implemented at all imo. The major problem with it being that the user will have to click twice to change the widget's value.

Answer (score 1):

Your requirement is weird. How ever the below are the few approaches

Changing the element text box to Select box means you totally changing the element and you can not convert input element to select element

The easiest approach is implementing the select box instead of text box.

The another approach is on change of the text box create new select box append to div and remove input control

The another approach is implementation of DataList which helps you with out any coding. Code is below

```
echo '<input list="gender">

<datalist id="gender">
  <option value="Male">
  <option value="Female">
</datalist>';
```